# Adding form content dynamically to jsp

Tags: html, forms, spring, jsp, struts

In my project, for every user the form elements like textbox, radiobox, button etc differ(type, number and order all can differ).
They need to be fetched from db per user.
I need your suggestions wrt to displaying and managing the content of the jsp in this regard.
Is there any tool or engine present to manage this kind of content display?

PS: I am using Struts and Spring integration framework.

Answer (score 0):

You should map your first request to the servlet and then dynamically generate your content based on user (Asssuming you know something in advance about user so that you can identify the user)

Comment: I am asking about the process to generate the content dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such free tool available to generate dynamic contents like textbox, radio, button etc.

You need to write a template.jsp , which will have if else block like

So here in template.jsp fetch types for this user from database and based on that iterate below for loop.

```
for(String type : types) {
    if(type.equals("textbox")) {
       // custom taglib for rendering textbox or textbox html tag
    } else  if(type.equals("radio")) {
       // custom taglib for rendering radio or radiohtml tag
    } ... and so on

}
```

Comment: I was looking for something more organized.